# Unix / Shell Add a range of columns to file

Tags: shell, sed, awk, dummy-data

So I've been trying the same problem for the last few days, and I'm at a formatting road block.

I have a program that will only run if its working on an equal number of columns. I know the total column count, and the number needed to add with a filler value of 0, but am not sure how to do this. Is there some time of range option with awk or sed for this?

Input:

```
A B C D E
A B C D E 1 1 1 1
```

Output:

```
A B C D E 0 0 0 0
A B C D E 1 1 1 1
```

The the alphabet columns are always present (with different values), but this "fill in the blank" function is eluding me. I can't use R for this due to data file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NF!=n{for(i=NF+1;i<=n;i++)$i=0}1' n=9 file
A B C D E 0 0 0 0
A B C D E 1 1 1 1
```

Just set `n` to the number of columns you want to pad upto.

Comment: This appears to be effective. My interpretation of this is...

If the number of fields in the current line is not equal to the maximum column count, do: for every NF+1 that is less than the max columns, set the next undefined column as equal to 0. At the end the function, print (1 = printing awk idiom? some kind of true value?)

Comment: Sorry! Of course I will. I was just reading through and trying to understand your one-liner.

Comment: @ashah57 yes you are correct in your understanding, it seems you added more to your comment after I wrote my first.

Comment: Yep, I didn't realize "shift+enter" == enter in the comment box.